# Logging from WebSphere Process Server

Tags: logging, windows-server-2008-r2, websphere-7, java.util.logging

We are look for a way to standardize the way we log errors across applications and platforms.

One of the alternatives is to use the Windows Event log.

Is it possible to log errors from WebSphere Process Server to a windows event log, without resorting to using custom Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On WebSphere, all log messages are routed through java.util.logging. That includes messages from the server itself and from applications, except for applications that configure their own logging. Therefore you would have to find an appender for java.util.logging that writes to the Windows event log. However, I don't think that something like that exists.